# Golang connect to docker connect to my sql docker getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose, mariadb

I am loosing my mind trying to set up my golang and docker env. I am using docker compose which seems to book both images fine but when I try run and go lang operations I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing in your yaml file is important, your mysql line should line up with your app line.

You have to add a

```
links:
  - mysql
```

line in under your `app:` section so it knows to connect the two.

Look here https://github.com/gpuenteallott/golang-mysql-docker-setup/blob/master/docker-compose.yml for a decent working example.

Comment: Hey man, My yaml was fine It just formatted that way here on stack, sorry .  But that link you gave me worked like a charm . Thanks very much